# Parsing Paypal payment

Tags: javascript, json, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i'm building a checkout using paypal. I've been working on this for two days and can't seem to figure out how to get the payment details to put into my DB

this is the error i'm getting when trying to JSON parse:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at https://######.com/######/quote.php?fname=######&lname=#####&email=########%40#########.com&tel=######&lot=7920&building=912&lotID=1:106:26
at e.n.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:11814)
at e.n.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:10871)
at e.n.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:12180)
at e.n.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:10871)
at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:11681
at e.n.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:11814)
at e.n.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:10871)
at e.n.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:12180)
Error: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at fr.error (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:62962)
at Object.<anonymous> (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:70732)
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at o (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:70591)
at xr (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:70744)
at Fr.u.on (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:75415)
at Fr (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:75552)
at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:81671
at Function.e.try (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:14344)
at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:81468
Error: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at fr.error (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:62962)
at Array.<anonymous> (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:70732)
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at o (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:70591)
at xr (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:70744)
at Fr.u.on (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:75415)
at Fr (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:75552)
at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:81671
at Function.e.try (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:14344)
at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQ4DspGAAbWgC9Iw0KoI0kWjiEx5xM_gqpAmw1gxFIUha1YDtA_TTmMCaYJH6j58L3HvIlNkN4hD7Wdc&disable-funding=credit,card:2:81468
```

this is my paypal button script

```
<script>
    
    paypal.Buttons({
        style:{
            color:'blue',
            shape:'pill'
        },createOrder: function (data, actions) {
    var cost = parseFloat(document.getElementsByClassName('totamount')[0].innerText.replace('$',''));
    var address = document.getElementsByClassName('product-name')[0].innerText;
    return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units : [{
            amount: {
                name: '####### ######',
                description: "##### #####at: " + address,
                value: cost
            }
        }]
    });
},
onApprove: function (data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
        console.log(details)
        var paydetails = JSON.parse(details);
        var payee = paydetails.payer.name.given_name + " " + paydetails.payer.name.surname;
        var payid = paydetails.id;
        console.log(payee);
        console.log(payid);
        //document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total')[0].innerHTML= JSON.stringify(details)
        //window.location.replace("https://######.com/######/paymentmade.php?uid=<?php echo $userid ?>")
    })
},
onCancel: function (data) {
    window.location.replace("https://#######.com/#######/quote.php?fname=<?php echo $fname ?> &lname=<?php echo $lname ?>&email=<?php echo $email ?>&tel=<?php echo $tel ?>&lot=<?php echo $lot ?>&building=<?php echo $building ?>&lotID=<?php echo $lotid ?>")
}
    }).render('#paypal-payment-button');</script>
<script src="include/script.js"></script>
```

i've tried Json parsing, and i've read a few other stackoverflow's pointing to using stuff like data.payID and things like that but those just give back undefined errors.

Comment: What does console log details.toString() show in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to get the payment details to put into my DB

If you need to store payment details in a database, you should not be using `actions.order.capture()` on the client side.

Instead, switch to a proper server integration.

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server